# Returning the address in the address box with google street view on a click event

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Using the Google Maps API I can return a street view of the current position using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. This throws up the address in a box at the left hand corner of the property image, along with a 'View in Google maps' link.

Is there a way to be able override the standard click event and capture the address (first line) in the box? Once I can show this in an alert the rest will follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That address is the [StreetViewLocation description](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/street-view-service#StreetViewLocation).

Access it when the `location_changed` event fires on the `panorama` with:

```
panorama.getLocation().description
```

`location_changed` listener:

```
panorama.addListener('location_changed', function() {
  var descriptionCell = document.getElementById('description');
  descriptionCell.innerHTML = panorama.getLocation().description + '';
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/u2hn6fc8/)

[image: screenshot of example map]

```js
(function(exports) {
  "use strict";

  function initialize() {
    exports.panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById("street-view"), {
        position: {
          lat: 37.86926,
          lng: -122.254811
        },
        pov: {
          heading: 165,
          pitch: 0
        },
        zoom: 1
      }
    );
    panorama.addListener('position_changed', function() {
      var positionCell = document.getElementById('position');
      positionCell.innerHTML = panorama.getPosition() + '';
    });
    panorama.addListener('location_changed', function() {
      var descriptionCell = document.getElementById('description');
      descriptionCell.innerHTML = panorama.getLocation().description + '';
    });
  }

  exports.initialize = initialize;
})((this.window = this.window || {}));
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10;
  padding: 0;
}

#street-view {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<title>Street View Containers</title>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="description"></div>
<div id="position"></div>
<div id="heading"></div>
<div id="pitch"></div>
<div id="street-view"></div>
```